# Согласования союзного слова с замещаемым или определяемым словом в главном предложении

Tags: согласование

Я по ходу даже рот грамотно не могу открыть, не поинтересовавшись предварительно здесь относительно того, как это сделать в соответствии с нормами русского литературного языка. 
Связь между вышесказанным и заголовком вопроса следующая.

В соседней теме я опубликовала предложение собственного сочинения: "Вместе с тем в справочнике ничего не сказано о том, что происходит, когда сложноподчиненное предложение не заканчивается новым предложением или дальнейшей частью того же предложения, с которыми связано повторяющееся слово". Здесь в качестве замещаемого слова в главном предложении, с которым согласуется союзное слово "который", выступают однородные дополнения "предложением" и "частью". Внимание, вопрос: не нарушено ли согласование в числе? Буду в высшей степени признательна за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласование верное: С КОТОРЫМИ - множественное число.

Союзное слова, следующее после ряда однородных существительных, имеет форму мн.числа: "В его лице выражалась не то печаль. не то радость, которые были и в природе, и в моем сердце".

Comment: Угу, благодарствуйте.